# Game came in a .zip file. How to install it?

Tags: software-installation, games, zip

I downloaded a game from http://floriandcp.itch.io/campfire and it came in a .zip file. I extracted the file but I can't find a way to install it.

That is the game that I'm trying to install. Can you guys help me?

Comment: What does the zipfile contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to actually install it. Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Downloads/linux64
```

Or wherever you extracted the file. If yours is a 32-bit system, then:

```
cd ~/Downloads/linux32
```

In either case, next do:

```
chmod +x campfire
./campfire
```

Play and enjoy!